Various high and low water pressure from taps after new pipes installed
We are on a well, installed all new pvc pipe. When i Turned on the main, water pressure gage is great but only some of the taps in the home have full pressure. Others in the home have just a trickle. Everything is new.. makes no sense..

Are the taps new also?  If not new, remove the aerators and clean.  Make sure all shutoff valves are fully open.  I am assuming you are trying one tap at a time.  The more taps open, the less pressure to some.

Likely options are:

Debris in pipes (particularly if cut with a saw, not pipe shears) or
debris from pipes that has lodged in valve orifices (more difficult to clean, may require cartridge removal)
or aerators (which are typically comparatively easy to clean.) Where a fixture has a stop valve and a fixture valve, debris can be in either or both.
Excess PVC glue creating a partial plug at some of the joints.


Or not having fully reopened some of the valves...
